# Deleting/Clearing django.contrib.messages

Tags: django

I want to conditionally clear `django.contrib.messages`. None of the solutions discussed in these two questions work:

[Delete all django.contrib.messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39518310/delete-all-django-contrib-messages)
[Django: Remove message before they are displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083164/django-remove-message-before-they-are-displayed)

Any suggestions on how I can clear the messages? I am using django 1.10

Code:

```
messages = get_messages(request)
for msg in messages:
    pass
for msg in messages._loaded:
    del msg
for msg in messages._queued_messages:
    del msg
```

Comment: Stumbled upon the same problem; maybe we need to create a custom storage/backend?

Comment: Maybe. Because of this issue, I ended up not using django.contrib.messages

Answer (score 14):

A one-liner would look like this:

```
list(messages.get_messages(request))
```

It essentially performs the same task as @Avukonke Peter's solution. However, I didn't find it necessary to set the messages as used (I believe this is done by default, but feel free to correct me if I'm wrong). It's beyond me why there's no `messages.clear()` function.

Comment: For some reason this works normally, but not in tests, i.e.`django-pytest` and using `django.test.Client()`.

Answer (score 12):

You need to iterate through the messages for your current set of messages as retrieved from the 'get_messages' method. You can use this code anywhere you want to clear the messages before setting new ones or where you want to simply clear all messages.

```
system_messages = messages.get_messages(request)
for message in system_messages:
    # This iteration is necessary
    pass
```

Note: If you do not want to clear messages, then set the system_messages.used flag to 'False' as the messages are marked to be cleared when the storage instance is iterated (and cleared when the response is processed).
Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/messages

Answer (score 3):

This is the only thing (other than overriding the `messages` block in the template) that worked for me in Django 4.*:

```py
from django.contrib.messages.storage import default_storage
request._messages = default_storage(request)
```

This is basically re-initialising the storage (like the messages middleware does).

Answer (score 1):

I am on Django 3.2 and none of the answers given here worked for me. Don't know why. Maybe it might be due to some changes in the newer versions. So I figured out a way to do this. If you need to delete the messages or you don't want to show the messages on a certain template, just iterate over the messages without doing anything in the template file.

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I added these lines in the template in which the messages should be deleted. Doing this in views is not possible now I guess. Still looking up for more insights on this by the community.